# Reset a whole column 30 days after signup

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site and in my wp_users table I have "user_registered" which is the registration date and "download_limit" which counts how many downloads the user have used. How do I reset a users download limit to 0 every 30 days after there signup date?

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with Wordpress, but in pure sql (MySql) the query could look something like this:

```
UPDATE wp_users
SET download_limit=0
WHERE
MOD(
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(
        DAY,
        user_registered, 
        NOW()
    ), 
    30
) = 0
```

The WHERE condition is where the magic happens. You take the difference in days between now and the subscription date. If that is divisible by 30, you know you need to reset their counter.

You may need to adjust this to reflect the correct column and table names. Also, if your subscription date is a timestamp, you'll probably need to wrap it in the `FROM_UNIXTIME` function.

And as @KhorneHoly correctly mentioned, you'll need to run this query once a day trough some sort of (lazy) cron mechanism.

Comment: I learned something from that, thank you. But there wouldn't be a way to do this backwards for dates that are older than 30 days, is there?

Comment: @KhorneHoly  sure, it should cover older dates as well. It just checks if the time difference between now and subscription *is divisible by 30*, so 60 days, 90 days, ... should be selected and updated as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need a script that runs at a daily basis. That script resets the download limit for all users meeting the conditions.

This script can either been fired up once a day with a cronjob or you start the script with the first visit of the day.

This could be something like:

1. user logs in -> function will be called
2. function checks if this function has been called before today (saved datetime in the database)
3. if not called run the function and update the datetime.

For the SQL, look at the answer from @Pevara

Comment: I understand that but what's the sql query? what would it look like?

Comment: @BradFletcher for the SQL have a look at Pevaras answer